# Missing Columns when Making Sparse Matrix (R)

Tags: r, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I have two data-sets `train`(this one containing the variables `date`,`store`,`item`)  and `test` (which has `id, date,store, item`) that I've combined into one `df_all` and then later partitioned again, because I'd like to eventually use the `train` dataset to create a model that predicts `sales`

the structure of `df_all` is

```
    'data.frame':   958000 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date : Factor w/ 1916 levels "2013-01-01","2013-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ store: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ item : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sales: num  13 11 14 13 10 12 10 9 12 9 ...
 $ id   : Factor w/ 45001 levels "0","1","10","100",..: 45001 45001 45001 45001 45001 45001 45001 45001 45001 45001 ...`
```

partitioned the data like:

```
set.seed(1234)
n = nrow(df_all)
index = sample(1:n, size = round(0.7*n), replace=T)
train = df_all[index, ]
test = df_all[-index, ]
```

and then used one-hot encoding because `id` is a categorical variable:

```
trainm <- sparse.model.matrix(sales ~ ., data= train)[,-1]
```

except this is where I run into my problem because my matrix ends up looking like

```
6 x 46917 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 20 column names ‘date2013-01-02’, ‘date2013-01-03’, ‘date2013-01-04’ ... ]]

108928 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
596163 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
583686 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
597198 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
824757 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
613418 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

108928 ......
596163 ......
583686 ......
597198 ......
824757 ......
613418 ......

 .....suppressing columns in show(); maybe adjust 'options(max.print= *, width = *)'
 ..............................
```

which doesn't look like the sparse matrix I need and there's odd situation happening with the columns not being how they should be (i.e. date, id, store, item, sales). So if anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this, or if there's another way to do it, that'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you want to one-hot encode only the `id` column ?

Comment: @YOLO uhm I guess encode all but sales, my response variable

Answer (score 2):

We should always do one-hot encoding before splitting the main dataset. Reason being, sometimes you might find values in test which are not in train, in such cases, you can't train/predict the model because there will be a mis-match in total number of columns.

Hence you should do:

```
# ohe columns
df_ohe <- model.matrix(~.-1, data = df_all[,-c('id','date')])

# join id column with ohe columns
df_all_new <- cbind(df_all[,1], df_ohe)
```

And, now you can split your data into train and test.

Comment: hey thanks for the explanation! Would you know how to get around an error like: `Error in -c("id", "date") : invalid argument to unary operator` ?